# Really strange IE 8 Beta 2 behaviour

Tags: sharepoint, moss, internet-explorer-8

PLEASE DON'T CLOSE -- IT'S PROGRAMMING-RELATED (BUT NO CODE INCLUDED)

I develop MOSS sites, and I need to make sure my sites are compatible with IE 7,8 and FireFox.

I have an external testing site (Windows 2003, IIS 6) and when I browse to this MOSS site, I can authenticate without any problems using IE8.

When I browse to my local installation of MOSS (Windows 2008 Server, IIS 7), I can't authenticate, instead it prompts for username+password, then 3 tries later a blank page comes up.

Any idea why this is? At the moment I can't test my MOSS installation locally using IE 8, because of this, and Microsoft don't provide support for beta products.

Comment: What's doing the authentication? If it's your code, you should be able to debug that. If it's IIS, try turning the logging up and see what it thinks is happening.

Answer (score 3):

You should try some network sniffing to see exactly what is happening over the wire. [WireShark](http://www.wireshark.org/) is pretty good.

Comment: or.. I could uninstall IE8 and go back to using 7 till Microsoft sort this bug out :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlertool.com/fiddler/) to see what status code IIS is returning to you.